# How to create dictionary key-values in django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I am developing server web with Django, and my model `ST_Folio` contains `idST` and `idFolio`, I need to create a dictionary `{idST: [idFolio1, idFolio2, ...]}`

But my problem is that I can create similar dictionary but no like I want.

I am using this method for this..

```
st_database = St_folio.objects.exclude(idST__isnull=True)
dictionary = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(st_database, key=lambda q: q.idST)}
```

and obtains this

First print (st_database):

```
<QuerySet [<St_folio: 1st_folio>, <St_folio: 2st_folio>, <St_folio: 3st_folio>]>
```

Second print (dictionary):

```
{<ST: st1>: [<St_folio: 1st_folio>, <St_folio: 2st_folio>], <ST: st2>: [<St_folio: 3st_folio>]}
```

I need thing like this:

```
{<ST: st1>: [<idFolio: folio1>, <idFolio: folio20>], <ST: st2>: [<idFolio: folio1>]}
```

My model ST_Folio

```
class St_folio(models.Model):
    idST = models.ForeignKey('ST', blank=True, null=True)
    idFolio = models.ForeignKey('Folio', blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('idST', 'idFolio'),)
    idPro = models.ForeignKey('Pro', blank=True, null=True)
    path_img = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    lng = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + "st_folio"
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Your question is quite vague. What is the purpose of the first and second, how are the models related?

Comment: First and Second are result from st_database and dictionary respectively. I'm sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could access the related objects and build a list from those:

```
dct = {k: [x.idFolio for x in g] for k, g in groupby(st_database, key=lambda q: q.idST)}
```

Also, note that `groupby` requires that the iterable be presorted, therefore, you may want to order your QuerySet befoere applying `groupby`:

```
st_database = St_folio.objects.exclude(idST__isnull=True).order_by('idST')
```

Or:

```
st_database = St_folio.objects.exclude(idST__isnull=True).order_by('idST_id')
```

in case you have a different field specified for `Meta.ordering`.

You can also add [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) to fetch the related object and optimize access to the related objects.

Comment: This solution work me, but I have a new problem with exclude, someone idFolio are Nulls and `St_folio.objects.exclude(idST__isnull=True, idFolio__isnull=True).order_by('idST')` not working fine for me, appears something this in my result `{<ST: st1>: [None, <Folio: folio1>], <ST: st2>: [<Folio: folio2>]}`, I need that not appears `None`. Thanks!

Comment: @fabulias Use separate `exclude`s: `St_folio.objects.exclude(idST__isnull=True).exclude(idFolio__isnull=True).order_by('idST')`

Comment: my result has a None idFolio, because that is Null in my database, I need not appears None (Folio) in my result. I add `idFolio__isnull=True` in my `exclude` and not working like I excepted.

Comment: @fabulias See my previous comment. You should use separate `exclude`s to remove objects with at least one `NULL`. And do remember to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Well bro, this solution work for me, but I have a ultimate problem, I can't return this data like JSON object, I do this `json_data = json.dumps(dct, default=json_serial)
        return HttpResponse(json_data, content_type="application/json")` and return this error `TypeError: keys must be a string`.

Comment: @fabulias Well bro, you need to ask a new question. I've been fair enough to debug related issues. This new one is quite unrelated.